# Attaching an xml file to webservices

Tags: c#

How can we attach an xml file to a webservice call.
I need to do in c#.
Any links appreciated.
i have googled and no c# results is coming.

by wse 3.0 onwards we can   attach xml file to webservice by using mtom
i have serached for links in c#.but not available. any links appreciated.

Thanks

supriya

Comment: Can't you pass xml file (red as string) as a parameter in webservice call?

Comment: requirement is to pass xml file as an attachment to webservice.

Comment: no.it is not wcf.it is a webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this may help you [Codeproject XML document loading](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/marcelo888RemoteScript02.aspx)